# How to show function parameters in IPython?

Tags: ipython

I read that pressing `shift+tab` after a function displays the function's docstring in an IPython notebook, but this does not seem to work in my IPython (no notebook). I run IPython 4.0.0 on Ubuntu.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Type a question mark behind the command

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The standard (console) IPython does not support the call tips via `<shift> + <tab>`. But a question mark before or after the function shows you the docstring:

```
In [1]: list.index?
Docstring:
L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of value.
Raises ValueError if the value is not present.
Type:      method_descriptor
```

As an alternative you can use the qtconsole version:

```
ipython qtconsole
```

Then:

```
In [1]: list.index(
```

Should show you a box with a call tip without pressing `<shift> + <tab>`:

[image]

Comment: In order to get this working I had to run `pip install qtconsole PyQt5`.
Also it seems this will be renamed to: `jupyter qtconsole` in the future.

Comment: How to show just the signature not the full doc?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, it works for jupyter notebook 5.6.0 version.

Comment: The question-asker specifically says this is not for a notebook.